# Convert object to array preserving index

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, object, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional object. The nesting object I need to convert to an array, I do it this way:

```
var foobar = {"foo1": { "5": "bar1", "8": "bar2" }, "foo2": { "3": "bar8", "5": "bar9" }};

angular.forEach(foobar, function(value, key) {
    if (angular.isObject(value)) {
        var arr = Object.keys(value).map(function(k) { return value[k]; });
        foobar[key] = arr;
    }
});

console.log(foobar);

{"foo1": ["bar1", "bar2"], "foo2": ["bar8", "bar9"]};
```

How do I convert object to array preserving index to make it come out like this:

```
{"foo1": [5 => "bar1", 8 => "bar2"], "foo2": [3 => "bar8", 5 => "bar9"]};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just try with:

```
angular.forEach(foobar, function(value, key) {
  if (angular.isObject(value)) {
    var arrValue = [];
    Object.keys(value).forEach(function(k) { arrValue[k] = value[k]; });
    foobar[key] = arrValue;
  }
});
```

Comment: IMHO it would be better to replace `map` with `each`, both will work, but using `map`  indicates that you are interested in the maped result. So it might look like an error in a later code review.

Comment: replacing `map` with `each` produces the error in angular: `TypeError: Object.keys(...).each is not a function`. Your original method using `map` accomplishes what I need. So I will accept the answer. But I did not envision that when I insert array with non-consequent index to `$location.search(foobar)` to make a query string out of it, it produces all array elements that were supposed to be before the provided index as `undefined`

Comment: To add to my previous comment: when I use `$location.search({"foo1": [3=> 'bar1']})`. it returns the following string: `http://website.com/path?foo1=undefined&foo1=undefined&foo1=bar1`. So I have to rethink the algorithm.

Comment: Ah sorry should be `forEach`  i mixed it up with the `Promise.each`